# Case statement for STI type column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sti

I have a `User` model that can have many `Websites`. For example, I will be able to call `User.websites` and it will pull up an ActiveRecord array of all of the websites that the User owns. But each website uses Single Table Inheritance (STI) and a `type` column that will determine the type of the website, like commercial, advertising, or forum. My problem is, that I was to make a case/when statement that runs a function if the the User has a website that is of a certain type. for example:

```
@user = User.first
case @user.websites
    when includes?(Commercial)
        'This user has a commercial website'
    when includes?(Forum)
        'This user has a forum website'
    when include?(Ad)
        'This user has a advertisement website'
end
```

Does anyone have a clue on the best way to do such a thing?

Comment: calling relation on a model rather than on instance object `@user` makes no sense at all

Comment: @JoeHalfFace I guess that was misleading, I will not be calling the modal itself. Just an instance of it. It was more of an example placeholder. I'll edit that. Thanks

Comment: what do these functions do? It does not seem like this logic should be the responsibility of the user model but rather the website model or another possibly PORO altogether. Right now if a users websites contains both Commercial and Forum sites only Commercial will execute and never Forum

Comment: @engineersmnky Does it really matter what the functions do? Lets say that all the functions do is output a string. I'll make an edit.

Comment: I have a solution but not sure what you mean by the best way

Comment: @JoeHalfFace I'm interested!

Comment: what do you expect, if `user` has more, that 1 type of a website in `user.websites`?

Comment: @sclem72 practically yes it does matter and what if a user has a Commercial website and a Forum website? Either way the user itself should not concern itself with such logic as it pertains to the website not the user. It's not just about writing code but making it easily maintainable in the future. This way you can define an appropriate interface for implementing any kind of website in the future without the need to make changes to models that should not be impacted.

Answer (score 4):

Shortest way to do this is using a the `map` method. Just one line!

```
   @user.websites.select(:type).uniq.map{
       |x| puts "This user has a #{x.type.downcase} website" 
   }
```

Or if you want to have these strings in an array.

```
@user.websites.select(:type).uniq.map{|x| x.type.downcase}
```

If you want to run functions. I would advice naming the functions in a friendly way such as `commercial_cost`, `forum_cost`, etc.. so that you can use the `send` method which makes your code compact.

```
@user.websites.select(:type).uniq.map{ |x| @user.send(x.type.downcase + "_cost") }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def types
  'This user has following websites: ' +  
     websites.pluck(:type).map(&:downcase).join(', ')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#user.rb

def return_data(*types)
  types.each do |t|
    if Website.where(:user_id => self.id, :type=> t).length>0
      send "method_for_owners_of_#{t}_site"
    end
  end
end

def method_for_owners_of_Commercial_site
end
#...

 @user.return_data(["Commercial"])
 @user.return_data(["Commercial", "Ad"])
 ...
```

According to Rails API

> When you do Firm.create(name: "37signals"), this record will be saved
>   in the companies table with type = “Firm”.

Comment: As a note this will execute n queries where n is the number of types supplied to the method. Even when the user instance can know through association whether or not it has a given type of site.